# Azure Kusto Query to produce a pivot with null values using a dynamic array as categories

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer

I would like to be able to generate a summary report from some time series data using Azure's Kusto language. The goal is to be able to produce a summary of counts of state over 2 distinct time periods (last day and last 3 days), but using the same categories for both regardless of whether the time period in question had an instance of a particular state.

Example data:

```
╔════════════╦═══════╗
║    date    ║ state ║
╠════════════╬═══════╣
║ 01/01/2020 ║ On    ║
║ 01/01/2020 ║ Off   ║
║ 01/01/2020 ║ error ║
║ 01/01/2020 ║ Off   ║
║ 01/01/2020 ║ Off   ║
║ 01/01/2020 ║ error ║
║ 01/01/2020 ║ error ║
║ 01/01/2020 ║ On    ║
║ 02/01/2020 ║ Off   ║
║ 02/01/2020 ║ Off   ║
║ 02/01/2020 ║ Off   ║
║ 02/01/2020 ║ Off   ║
║ 02/01/2020 ║ On    ║
║ 02/01/2020 ║ Off   ║
║ 02/01/2020 ║ error ║
║ 02/01/2020 ║ On    ║
║ 02/01/2020 ║ On    ║
║ 02/01/2020 ║ On    ║
║ 02/01/2020 ║ On    ║
║ 02/01/2020 ║ On    ║
║ 02/01/2020 ║ On    ║
║ 02/01/2020 ║ Off   ║
║ 02/01/2020 ║ error ║
║ 02/01/2020 ║ error ║
║ 02/01/2020 ║ error ║
║ 02/01/2020 ║ error ║
║ 02/01/2020 ║ error ║
║ 02/01/2020 ║ error ║
║ 02/01/2020 ║ On    ║
║ 02/01/2020 ║ On    ║
║ 02/01/2020 ║ On    ║
║ 02/01/2020 ║ On    ║
║ 02/01/2020 ║ Off   ║
║ 03/01/2020 ║ Off   ║
║ 03/01/2020 ║ error ║
║ 03/01/2020 ║ On    ║
║ 03/01/2020 ║ Off   ║
║ 03/01/2020 ║ Off   ║
║ 03/01/2020 ║ Off   ║
║ 03/01/2020 ║ Off   ║
║ 03/01/2020 ║ On    ║
║ 03/01/2020 ║ On    ║
║ 03/01/2020 ║ Off   ║
║ 03/01/2020 ║ Off   ║
║ 03/01/2020 ║ error ║
║ 03/01/2020 ║ error ║
║ 03/01/2020 ║ On    ║
║ 03/01/2020 ║ Off   ║
║ 03/01/2020 ║ Off   ║
║ 03/01/2020 ║ Off   ║
║ 03/01/2020 ║ error ║
║ 03/01/2020 ║ On    ║
║ 03/01/2020 ║ Off   ║
║ 03/01/2020 ║ error ║
║ 03/01/2020 ║ On    ║
║ 03/01/2020 ║ Off   ║
║ 03/01/2020 ║ Off   ║
║ 03/01/2020 ║ Off   ║
║ 03/01/2020 ║ Off   ║
║ 03/01/2020 ║ Off   ║
║ 03/01/2020 ║ error ║
║ 03/01/2020 ║ error ║
║ 03/01/2020 ║ Off   ║
║ 03/01/2020 ║ Off   ║
║ 03/01/2020 ║ Off   ║
║ 03/01/2020 ║ Off   ║
║ 03/01/2020 ║ Off   ║
║ 03/01/2020 ║ error ║
║ 03/01/2020 ║ On    ║
║ 03/01/2020 ║ On    ║
║ 03/01/2020 ║ On    ║
║ 03/01/2020 ║ On    ║
║ 04/01/2020 ║ On    ║
║ 04/01/2020 ║ Off   ║
║ 04/01/2020 ║ Off   ║
║ 04/01/2020 ║ Off   ║
║ 04/01/2020 ║ Off   ║
║ 04/01/2020 ║ Off   ║
║ 04/01/2020 ║ Off   ║
║ 04/01/2020 ║ Off   ║
║ 04/01/2020 ║ Off   ║
║ 04/01/2020 ║ On    ║
║ 05/01/2020 ║ On    ║
║ 05/01/2020 ║ On    ║
║ 05/01/2020 ║ On    ║
║ 05/01/2020 ║ On    ║
╚════════════╩═══════╝
```

To illustrate the point, creating a pivot in excel *almost* does what I need:

```
╔════════════╦═══════════════╗
║ Row Labels ║ Count of date ║
╠════════════╬═══════════════╣
║ 01/01/2020 ║             8 ║
║  error     ║             3 ║
║  Off       ║             3 ║
║  On        ║             2 ║
║ 02/01/2020 ║            25 ║
║  error     ║             7 ║
║  Off       ║             7 ║
║  On        ║            11 ║
║ 03/01/2020 ║            39 ║
║  error     ║             8 ║
║  Off       ║            21 ║
║  On        ║            10 ║
║ 04/01/2020 ║            10 ║
║  Off       ║             8 ║
║  On        ║             2 ║
║ 05/01/2020 ║             4 ║
║  On        ║             4 ║
╚════════════╩═══════════════╝
```

What I need the Kusto query to do is to generate a table as follows:

```
╔════════════╦═══════════════╗
║ Row Labels ║ Count of date ║
╠════════════╬═══════════════╣
║ 01/01/2020 ║             8 ║
║  error     ║             3 ║
║  Off       ║             3 ║
║  On        ║             2 ║
║ 02/01/2020 ║            25 ║
║  error     ║             7 ║
║  Off       ║             7 ║
║  On        ║            11 ║
║ 03/01/2020 ║            39 ║
║  error     ║             8 ║
║  Off       ║            21 ║
║  On        ║            10 ║
║ 04/01/2020 ║            10 ║
║  **error** ║             0 ║
║  Off       ║             8 ║
║  On        ║             2 ║
║ 05/01/2020 ║             4 ║
║  **error** ║             0 ║
║  **Off**   ║             0 ║
║  On        ║             4 ║
╚════════════╩═══════════════╝
```

Note on 4/1/2020 and 5/1/2020 there are 0 values for categories that didn't occur on those dates.

I have tried using `summarize` but cannot work out how to use a preset list of categories and default to 0 where needed.

```
data
| summarize count(state) by bin(date, 1d), state
```

Any hints on how this can achieved, would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you could "settle" for a different output schema (which, one could argue, is more 'convenient' to work with), you could try the following approach:

**output:**

```
| dt                          | sum_count_ | On | Off | error |
|-----------------------------|------------|----|-----|-------|
| 2020-01-01 00:00:00.0000000 | 8          | 2  | 3   | 3     |
| 2020-02-01 00:00:00.0000000 | 25         | 11 | 7   | 7     |
| 2020-03-01 00:00:00.0000000 | 39         | 10 | 21  | 8     |
| 2020-04-01 00:00:00.0000000 | 10         | 2  | 8   |       |
| 2020-05-01 00:00:00.0000000 | 4          | 4  |     |       |
```

**query:**

```
datatable(dt:datetime, state:string)
[
    datetime(01/01/2020), 'On',
    datetime(01/01/2020), 'Off',
    datetime(01/01/2020), 'error',
    datetime(01/01/2020), 'Off',
    datetime(01/01/2020), 'Off',
    datetime(01/01/2020), 'error',
    datetime(01/01/2020), 'error',
    datetime(01/01/2020), 'On',
    datetime(02/01/2020), 'Off',
    datetime(02/01/2020), 'Off',
    datetime(02/01/2020), 'Off',
    datetime(02/01/2020), 'Off',
    datetime(02/01/2020), 'On',
    datetime(02/01/2020), 'Off',
    datetime(02/01/2020), 'error',
    datetime(02/01/2020), 'On',
    datetime(02/01/2020), 'On',
    datetime(02/01/2020), 'On',
    datetime(02/01/2020), 'On',
    datetime(02/01/2020), 'On',
    datetime(02/01/2020), 'On',
    datetime(02/01/2020), 'Off',
    datetime(02/01/2020), 'error',
    datetime(02/01/2020), 'error',
    datetime(02/01/2020), 'error',
    datetime(02/01/2020), 'error',
    datetime(02/01/2020), 'error',
    datetime(02/01/2020), 'error',
    datetime(02/01/2020), 'On',
    datetime(02/01/2020), 'On',
    datetime(02/01/2020), 'On',
    datetime(02/01/2020), 'On',
    datetime(02/01/2020), 'Off',
    datetime(03/01/2020), 'Off',
    datetime(03/01/2020), 'error',
    datetime(03/01/2020), 'On',
    datetime(03/01/2020), 'Off',
    datetime(03/01/2020), 'Off',
    datetime(03/01/2020), 'Off',
    datetime(03/01/2020), 'Off',
    datetime(03/01/2020), 'On',
    datetime(03/01/2020), 'On',
    datetime(03/01/2020), 'Off',
    datetime(03/01/2020), 'Off',
    datetime(03/01/2020), 'error',
    datetime(03/01/2020), 'error',
    datetime(03/01/2020), 'On',
    datetime(03/01/2020), 'Off',
    datetime(03/01/2020), 'Off',
    datetime(03/01/2020), 'Off',
    datetime(03/01/2020), 'error',
    datetime(03/01/2020), 'On',
    datetime(03/01/2020), 'Off',
    datetime(03/01/2020), 'error',
    datetime(03/01/2020), 'On',
    datetime(03/01/2020), 'Off',
    datetime(03/01/2020), 'Off',
    datetime(03/01/2020), 'Off',
    datetime(03/01/2020), 'Off',
    datetime(03/01/2020), 'Off',
    datetime(03/01/2020), 'error',
    datetime(03/01/2020), 'error',
    datetime(03/01/2020), 'Off',
    datetime(03/01/2020), 'Off',
    datetime(03/01/2020), 'Off',
    datetime(03/01/2020), 'Off',
    datetime(03/01/2020), 'Off',
    datetime(03/01/2020), 'error',
    datetime(03/01/2020), 'On',
    datetime(03/01/2020), 'On',
    datetime(03/01/2020), 'On',
    datetime(03/01/2020), 'On',
    datetime(04/01/2020), 'On',
    datetime(04/01/2020), 'Off',
    datetime(04/01/2020), 'Off',
    datetime(04/01/2020), 'Off',
    datetime(04/01/2020), 'Off',
    datetime(04/01/2020), 'Off',
    datetime(04/01/2020), 'Off',
    datetime(04/01/2020), 'Off',
    datetime(04/01/2020), 'Off',
    datetime(04/01/2020), 'On',
    datetime(05/01/2020), 'On',
    datetime(05/01/2020), 'On',
    datetime(05/01/2020), 'On',
    datetime(05/01/2020), 'On',
]
| summarize count() by dt, state
| summarize sum(count_), b = make_bag(pack(state, count_)) by dt
| evaluate bag_unpack(b)
```

if you can't settle, but can make assumptions on the contents of the `state` column (e.g. that its values are either `On`, `Off`, or `error`) then you could try this:

**output:**

```
| RowLabel         | Count |
|------------------|-------|
| 01/01/2020 Total | 8     |
| 01/01/2020 Error | 3     |
| 01/01/2020 On    | 2     |
| 01/01/2020 Off   | 3     |
| 02/01/2020 Total | 25    |
| 02/01/2020 Error | 7     |
| 02/01/2020 On    | 11    |
| 02/01/2020 Off   | 7     |
| 03/01/2020 Total | 39    |
| 03/01/2020 Error | 8     |
| 03/01/2020 On    | 10    |
| 03/01/2020 Off   | 21    |
| 04/01/2020 Total | 10    |
| 04/01/2020 Error | 0     |
| 04/01/2020 On    | 2     |
| 04/01/2020 Off   | 8     |
| 05/01/2020 Total | 4     |
| 05/01/2020 Error | 0     |
| 05/01/2020 On    | 4     |
| 05/01/2020 Off   | 0     |
```

**query:**

```
datatable(dt:datetime, state:string)
[
    datetime(01/01/2020), 'On',
    datetime(01/01/2020), 'Off',
    datetime(01/01/2020), 'error',
    datetime(01/01/2020), 'Off',
    datetime(01/01/2020), 'Off',
    datetime(01/01/2020), 'error',
    datetime(01/01/2020), 'error',
    datetime(01/01/2020), 'On',
    datetime(02/01/2020), 'Off',
    datetime(02/01/2020), 'Off',
    datetime(02/01/2020), 'Off',
    datetime(02/01/2020), 'Off',
    datetime(02/01/2020), 'On',
    datetime(02/01/2020), 'Off',
    datetime(02/01/2020), 'error',
    datetime(02/01/2020), 'On',
    datetime(02/01/2020), 'On',
    datetime(02/01/2020), 'On',
    datetime(02/01/2020), 'On',
    datetime(02/01/2020), 'On',
    datetime(02/01/2020), 'On',
    datetime(02/01/2020), 'Off',
    datetime(02/01/2020), 'error',
    datetime(02/01/2020), 'error',
    datetime(02/01/2020), 'error',
    datetime(02/01/2020), 'error',
    datetime(02/01/2020), 'error',
    datetime(02/01/2020), 'error',
    datetime(02/01/2020), 'On',
    datetime(02/01/2020), 'On',
    datetime(02/01/2020), 'On',
    datetime(02/01/2020), 'On',
    datetime(02/01/2020), 'Off',
    datetime(03/01/2020), 'Off',
    datetime(03/01/2020), 'error',
    datetime(03/01/2020), 'On',
    datetime(03/01/2020), 'Off',
    datetime(03/01/2020), 'Off',
    datetime(03/01/2020), 'Off',
    datetime(03/01/2020), 'Off',
    datetime(03/01/2020), 'On',
    datetime(03/01/2020), 'On',
    datetime(03/01/2020), 'Off',
    datetime(03/01/2020), 'Off',
    datetime(03/01/2020), 'error',
    datetime(03/01/2020), 'error',
    datetime(03/01/2020), 'On',
    datetime(03/01/2020), 'Off',
    datetime(03/01/2020), 'Off',
    datetime(03/01/2020), 'Off',
    datetime(03/01/2020), 'error',
    datetime(03/01/2020), 'On',
    datetime(03/01/2020), 'Off',
    datetime(03/01/2020), 'error',
    datetime(03/01/2020), 'On',
    datetime(03/01/2020), 'Off',
    datetime(03/01/2020), 'Off',
    datetime(03/01/2020), 'Off',
    datetime(03/01/2020), 'Off',
    datetime(03/01/2020), 'Off',
    datetime(03/01/2020), 'error',
    datetime(03/01/2020), 'error',
    datetime(03/01/2020), 'Off',
    datetime(03/01/2020), 'Off',
    datetime(03/01/2020), 'Off',
    datetime(03/01/2020), 'Off',
    datetime(03/01/2020), 'Off',
    datetime(03/01/2020), 'error',
    datetime(03/01/2020), 'On',
    datetime(03/01/2020), 'On',
    datetime(03/01/2020), 'On',
    datetime(03/01/2020), 'On',
    datetime(04/01/2020), 'On',
    datetime(04/01/2020), 'Off',
    datetime(04/01/2020), 'Off',
    datetime(04/01/2020), 'Off',
    datetime(04/01/2020), 'Off',
    datetime(04/01/2020), 'Off',
    datetime(04/01/2020), 'Off',
    datetime(04/01/2020), 'Off',
    datetime(04/01/2020), 'Off',
    datetime(04/01/2020), 'On',
    datetime(05/01/2020), 'On',
    datetime(05/01/2020), 'On',
    datetime(05/01/2020), 'On',
    datetime(05/01/2020), 'On',
]
| summarize Total = count(),
            Error = countif(state == "error"),
            On = countif(state == "On"), 
            Off = countif(state == "Off") 
         by dt
| project dt, p = pack("Total", Total, "Error", Error, "On", On, "Off", Off)
| mv-apply p on (
    extend key = tostring(bag_keys(p)[0])
    | project RowLabel = strcat(format_datetime(dt, "MM/dd/yyyy"), " ", key),
              Count = p[key]
)
| project-away dt
```

Comment: Thanks @Yoni. The issue is I need the 0 values for all categories of state on each date. I am trying to use the `Polystat` widget in grafana to display rows for last 3 hours, 24 hours and 72 hours so need the polygons to "line up" vertically for visual convenience when trying to quickly read the states over those periods.

Thanks for the query though. I have not used many of those features before.

Comment: Thanks @yoni - Masterclass in Azure Kusto and does what I want. As an extension, I am going to try working out how to use what you have shown me above to work with a totally dynamic set of states. For instance, the list of response codes can change over a period - 2xx, 3xx, 400, 401, 404 codes over a 3 day period, then additionally some 428 and 504 codes on the next day. It would be great therefore to have the same 0-filled summary but for the dynamic list, with the 3-day superset of response codes used for 72, 24 and 3 hours. I will try and update this thread once I have had a play. Thanks